# Maven Dependency Plugin Not Using Parameters

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to `unpack-dependencies` to a directory based on the artifact name.

To this end, I tried using the `useSubDirectoryPerArtifact=true` parameter but it appears that maven is not recognising this.

The exact command I am using is:

```
mvn -X dependency:unpack-dependencies -DincludeClassifiers=x86-win-vc80 -DoverWriteReleases=true -DoverWriteSnapshots=true -DuseSubDirectoryPerArtifact=true -DoutputDirectory=<OUTPUT_DIRECTORY>
```

When I view the debug output, I get something containing the following extract:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) silent = false
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stripClassifier = false
[DEBUG]   (s) stripVersion = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useJvmChmod = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useRepositoryLayout = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerArtifact = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerScope = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerType = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Note that this behaviour is being exhibited by all of `useSubDirectoryPerArtifact`, `useSubDirectoryPerScope` and `useSubDirectoryPerType`, but that the other properties (such as the overwrites and the output directory) are being set correctly.

Is there something which I am doing incorrectly here, or is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing `useSubDirectoryPerArtifact=true` to `mdep.useSubDirectoryPerArtifact=true`

The property to override is identified in the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html#useSubDirectoryPerArtifact) as **user.property**.

Note how this could be different (as it was in this case) to the name of the property.